# How to Create a Line Buffer from a Data Frame Border in R/Python

Tags: python, r, coordinates, geojson, qgis

I have a data frame representing a border with longitude and latitude coordinates. I need to create a line buffer at a distance of 20 km from this border, but only on one side (left)(e.g., west and south, but this side can change). I've attempted to use R and the st_buffer function, but it only provides me with circular buffers, not a line. Can someone help me with Python or R code to achieve this?

My data:

```
id      long      lat
1  13.75873 60.43691
2  13.76508 60.43032
3  13.76412 60.41860
4  13.76378 60.41610
5  13.76174 60.40868
6  13.75852 60.39951
7  13.75661 60.39255
8  13.75178 60.38731
9  13.73603 60.37975
10 13.73401 60.37771
11 13.73481 60.37146
12 13.74191 60.36131
13 13.75218 60.34841
14 12.95308 59.28652
15 12.92636 59.24958
16 12.91354 59.24680
17 12.84433 59.25892
18 12.81312 59.26769
19 12.79649 59.27055
20 12.77692 59.26879
21 12.75974 59.26371
22 12.75056 59.26391
23 12.74033 59.26335
24 12.73270 59.26140
25 12.72690 59.26008
26 12.71117 59.26290
27 12.69707 59.26618
28 12.69542 59.26616
29 12.69261 59.26163
30 12.65590 59.23614
```

Comment: Hello! I would like some extra specifics to make sure we can answer this question in the most helpful way. Please include what packages you are using as well as the function that you are using to plot these coordinates so community members can better follow your workflow.

Comment: start by transforming your points to a linestring 

line <- st_cast(st_union(sf_df), "LINESTRING")